# Python adding elements to dict and to defaultdict

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

There is ordinary dict:

```
ordinarydict = {}
ordinarydict['somekey']
print ordinarydict
```

I'll get an error. `KeyError "somekey"`
And this is expected behavior.

So, there is defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
d['somekey']
print d

>>> defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'somekey': 0})
```

I didn't add anything in dict, I just called dictionary with invalid key. But now new element was added to defaultdict.

Comment: ...because that's exactly what `defaultdict` is for? https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Comment: PS: "can someone explain the next thing": this site is not read one message after the other, we don't know what the "last thing" was.  Each question is independent of all the others.

Comment: Have you tried looking at [the docs for `defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)? Or typing `help(defaultdict)` in the interactive interpreter? In general, documentation that people slaved over is going to be a lot more readable than something that you demand someone write up on the spur of the moment. If you've read the docs and can't understand something, then you have a specific question to ask (and possibly a docs bug report to submit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the whole point of defaultdict: you construct one with a callable (in this case, `int`), and when a key is accessed that doesn't exist, it will call it (producing `0`), and insert it into the dictionary.  It auto-creates keys as you access them.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `defaultdict` by default adds the missing key to the dictionary, as can be seen in the [source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/37ebb0d44808/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#l1396).

This behaviour is also documented in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict.__missing__):

> > > If default_factory is not None, it is called without arguments to provide a default value for the given key, this value is inserted in the dictionary for the key, and returned.